# try catch doesn't work with sse

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, server-sent-events

This is the code, **P.S: the service httpd in s10 is stopped**

```
        try {
            var source = new EventSource("http://s10/server.php");
            console.log(source);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ADSfasfasfasdfasdfas" + e)
        }
```

this is the console:
[image]

why the heck the try catch is not catching the error ??

ofcourse I have onerror event and onclose event:

```
        source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
            if (source.readyState == 2) {
                connectionClosed();//to change some style
                console.log("Disconnected");
            }

        }, false);

        source.onerror = function(e) {
            if (source.readyState != 0) {
                connectionClosed();//to change some style
                console.log("Disconnected");
            }
        };
        source.onclose = function() {
            connectionClosed();//to change some style
            console.log('Connection closed');
        }
```

Comment: `try..catch` can only handle errors thrown in the same call stack, limiting it to synchronous operations or the small fragment at the beginning of asynchronous operations that is synchronous. Also, are you certain the errors aren't being handled by the `onerror` or `'error'` bindings? Handled errors, especially those that are network-related, don't necessarily go without being mentioned in the log; but, a mention may be all that's occurring. Have you tried binding to [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror)?

Comment: well, `window.onerror` didn't work :), and I'm sure that i bind the `onerror` event, but what do you mean with `error` ?

Answer (score 0):

When I run this in the Console on an arbitrary URL that isn't set up to handle SourceEvents, the Console successfully logs a SourceEvent instance. This is similar to what you're describing.

[image: SourceEvent]

So my guess here is that there's no error to catch. The SourceEvent instance is successfully constructed, even though there's no actual connection. If you want to detect if the connection is working, use the `EventSource.readyState` property.

In my screenshot you can see that `readyState = 0`, which means that the connection is "connecting", but in reality it's never going to finish connecting because the server on the other side isn't set up to handle SourceEvents.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource/readyState

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing the same thing, the `onerror` doesn't provide really useful info. For example, if you shut down your server or if you send an empty response while your client is connected, you can't detect programmatically on the client side the specific cause, I can see that just inspecting the dev console.